# Can I use different Hibernate batch sizes depending on the entity or table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am wondering if it
a) makes sense and
b) is possible
to use different create batch sizes for different entities?

Example:

- I have one table `A` with millions or rows, but only a few small columns. For this table I could set the batch value to about 100 or even 1000.
- However, another table `B` contains a column with some thousand bytes of data which are filled on insert. For this table I thinks I should only use a batch value between 1 and 10.

Maybe I can use an own implementation of `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.BatchBuilder` where I set the batch size in dependence of the entity to be inserted? (By setting the hibernate property `hibernate.jdbc.batch.builder`.)

Does that sound logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems to be correct. The default implementation `BatchBuilder` is `BatchBuilderImpl` and within the `buildBatch` method one of the parameters passed is `BatchKey`. This is of format (fully qualified entity class name)#(type of operation>
E.g., com.test.A#INSERT.

```
public class BatchBuilderImpl implements BatchBuilder, Configurable, Manageable, BatchBuilderMXBean { .......

@Override
    public Batch buildBatch(BatchKey key, JdbcCoordinator jdbcCoordinator) {
        final Integer sessionJdbcBatchSize = jdbcCoordinator.getJdbcSessionOwner()
                .getJdbcBatchSize();
        final int jdbcBatchSizeToUse = sessionJdbcBatchSize == null ?
                this.jdbcBatchSize :
                sessionJdbcBatchSize;
        return jdbcBatchSizeToUse > 1
                ? new BatchingBatch( key, jdbcCoordinator, jdbcBatchSizeToUse )
                : new NonBatchingBatch( key, jdbcCoordinator );
    }

}
```

Within your customized implementation you can set the batch size by loading configurations from external file containing the entity class and corresponding batch sizes. The batch size would then depend upon the first portion of BatchKey.

Comment: Thanks, for confirming my suggestion. But I miss the part, if it makes sense to use different batch sizes for different entities. Why did nobody before implement this? Maybe its is not worth the effort?

Comment: Maybe because you can set batch size in dao when you make a query to the database.

Comment: @A.Alexander my dao with Hibernate either uses the EntityManager or is a Spring CrudRepository. In both cases I can't see, how to set a batch size. Can you explain what exactly you mean?

Comment: @Datz - when using batch especially with Hibernate you have to keep in mind the memory requirements as well. And that is because That is because Hibernate caches all the newly inserted/updated instances in the session-level cache so your save operation would need to be synched with the appropriate batch size. Also you have an entity type containing batch which itself requires lot of memory so it may need to have different batch. Check the docs here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch-insert